# TFPT.EXE CreateTeamProject - TF30155: Error occurred while trying to create project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

I am using the command  -

```
tfpt.exe createteamproject /collection:url /teamproject:"Projectname" /processtemplate:CMMI /noportal
```

from command prompt to create a new Team project in Visual Studio Team services(VSTS).
In VSTS I have created a free trial account and using this url and credentials to create the team project.

When I run the above command in command prompt I get an error exception. Detailed log is attached below.

**Please note-** I do not have any developer/programming background, I am just looking to automate this task using powershell
I have visual studio 2013 and TFS 2013 power tools installed on the machine where I am running this command.
Has anyone seen this error before?

> C:\Windows\system32>tfpt.exe createteamproject /collection:https://hmsutar.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /teamproject:Mycode /processtemplate:scrum /noportal

```
All provided settings are valid.
---begin Exception entry---
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating the project structure on hmsutar.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection.
Exception Details:
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Message: The requested operation is not allowed. (type SoapException
SoapException Details: <detail ServerTimeStamp="2016-03-16T09:56:11:045" ExceptionMessage="The requested operation is not allowed." BaseExceptionName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerException" />
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.CommonStructureService.CreateProject(String projectName, XmlElement structure)
 --- end Exception entry ---
 ---begin Exception entry---
Exception Message: TF200016: The following project does not exist: Mycode. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Team Foundation Server. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: <det
l ServerTimeStamp="2016-03-16T09:56:11:873" ExceptionMessage="TF200016: The following project does not exist: Mycode. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Team Foundation Server." BaseexceptionName="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectException" />
Exception Stack Trace:at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.CommonStructureService.GetProjectFromName(String projectName)
--- end Exception entry ---
2016-03-16T02:56:12 | Module: BatchTeamProjectCreator | Thread: 1 | Microsoft.visualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationException: The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating the project structure on hmsutar.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating the project structure on hmsutar.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection. ---> System.Web.Services.protocols.SoapException: The requested operation is not allowed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Log file has been created at "C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Temp\Mycode.log".
Check the log for detailed results.
```

Logs

```
-----from log file--
2016-03-16T02:56:10 | Module: CssStructureUploader | Thread: 5 | Uploading CSS structure: "<Nodes><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Iteration" xmlns=""><Children><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 1" /><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 2" /><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 3" /><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 4" /><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 5" /><Node StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" Name="Sprint 6" /></Children></Node><Node StructureType="ProjectModelHierarchy" Name="Area" xmlns="" /></Nodes>"
2016-03-16T02:56:10 | Module: CssStructureUploader | Thread: 5 | Creating Project : Mycode
2016-03-16T02:56:11 | Module: CssStructureUploader | Thread: 5 | TF30155: Error occurred while trying to create project : "Mycode"
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2016-03-16T02:56:11
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "UploadStructure" from Group "Classification" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating the project structure on hmsutar.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection.
Exception Details: 
The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating the project structure on hmsutar.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection. 
The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. 
Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish 
creating the Team Project.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.CssStructureUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Team Servives, you need to use the Web UI or the REST Api to create a new Team project. The API Reference can be found here:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/tfs/projects#Createateamproject

To pass the correct Process template ID you can query the available process templates here:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfs/processes#Getalistofprocesses

A simple powershell script or a small Console appliation would allow you to call these from the commandline. A small template and creative use of Curl or wget might also work.